# Problems with a shared mutable?

Tags: python

```
def set_if_not_there(d, fields, default_value=None):
    for field in fields:
        if not field in d:
            d[field] = default_value

d = { }

set_if_not_there(d, ['cnt1', 'cnt2'], 0)
set_if_not_there(d, ['tags1', 'tags2'], [])

d['cnt1'] += 1
d['tags1'].append('work')

print d
```

The output is:

```
{'tags2': ['work'], 'cnt2': 0, 'cnt1': 1, 'tags1': ['work']}
```

As you can see, `tags1` and `tags2` are actually refering to the same list, which is not intended. `cnt1` and `cnt2` are working fine.

How can I implement `set_if_not_there` so that I create `copies` of the mutable, but only when needed? That is, if default value is a "scalar" (int, string, `None`, ...) no copy is needed, but for lists and dicts a copy is necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a factory function instead of a default value:

```
def set_if_not_there(d, fields, default_factory=None):
    if default_factory is None:
        default_factory = lambda: None
    for field in fields:
        if not field in d:
            d[field] = default_factory()
```

and pass in callables (like functions or lambdas, or default types):

```
set_if_not_there(d, ['cnt1', 'cnt2'], int)
set_if_not_there(d, ['tags1', 'tags2'], list)
```

`int()` returns `0`, `list()` returns a new empty list.

This is what the standard library [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) type does as well, for example.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> set_if_not_there(d, ['cnt1', 'cnt2'], int)
>>> set_if_not_there(d, ['tags1', 'tags2'], list)
>>> d['cnt1'] += 1
>>> d['tags1'].append('work')
>>> print d
{'tags2': [], 'cnt2': 0, 'cnt1': 1, 'tags1': ['work']}
```

Comment: +1 I need to print this approach into my mind, as it's so filled with good points!

Comment: Thanks! Anything against `default_factory = default_factory or lambda: None`?

Comment: That would not let you detect an error like `set_if_not_there(d, ['cnt1', 'cnt2'], False)` (where you meant to use `lambda: False` instead).

Answer (score 2):

you just need **copy.deepcopy**.

```
import copy
def set_if_not_there(d, fields, default_value=None):
    for field in fields:
        if not field in d:
            d[field] = copy.deepcopy(default_value)

d = { }

set_if_not_there(d, ['cnt1', 'cnt2'], 0)
set_if_not_there(d, ['tags1', 'tags2'], [])

d['cnt1'] += 1
d['tags1'].append('work')

print d
```

result:

```
>>> 
{'tags2': [], 'cnt2': 0, 'cnt1': 1, 'tags1': ['work']}
```

I think my way is more flexible,because you can define the default_value not just empty one.if you try:

```
set_if_not_there(d, ['cnt1', 'cnt2'], 0)
set_if_not_there(d, ['tags1', 'tags2'], [0,1])

d['cnt1'] += 1
d['tags1'].append('work')

print d
```

you will get:

```
{'tags2': [0, 1], 'cnt2': 0, 'cnt1': 1, 'tags1': [0, 1, 'work']}
```

if you really prefer to avoid import **,you can try:

```
def set_if_not_there(d, fields, default_value=lambda:None):
    for field in fields:
        if not field in d:
            d[field] = default_value()

d = { }

set_if_not_there(d, ['cnt1', 'cnt2'], lambda:0)
set_if_not_there(d, ['tags1', 'tags2'], lambda:[0,1])
```

also works